# jquery trigger event on change inputs in div

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to set a var on change of 1 of many inputs in a div, something like:

```
$('#afwijkende_prijzen_vak'+nexty).find('input:text').val('');
```

If there changes a input in that div (text, select or radio) i wat to set a var to recognize a change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what "set a var to recognize a change" means exactly, but here's what I'd do to change a variable when an input inside a particular element is changed:

```
var myVar;

$('#someDiv input, #someDiv select').each(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
        // do stuff with things
        myVar = 42;
    });
});
```

Or:

```
$('#someDiv').find('input, select').each(function() { ... });
```